# I have got below security alert from play store

Tags: java, android, bouncycastle, pgp, spongycastle

•   Security alert
Your app contains unsafe cryptographic encryption patterns. Please see this Google Help Center article for details.
Vulnerable classes:
o   org.spongycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePBEKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator.encryptSessionInfo